# Mounting the volume /var/opt/mssql is causing the schema created in entrypoint.sh to be lost when running SQL Server container

Tags: sql-server, docker, dockerfile

I'm following the tutorial https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/tree/master/linux/preview/examples/mssql-customize to build a Docker image base on `mssql/server:2019-latest`. I want the data to be persistent to restarts, so I tried to mount the volume in `/var/opt/mssql`. However, if I mount the volume there, the T-SQL that I want to customize SQL Server with does not run. The data is actually persisted, but I want to run with some pre-installed schema, which I'm struggling with.

This is my bash command

```
docker run --rm --user=root --platform linux/amd64 -d --name mssqlserver -p 1433:1433 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=StrongPassw0rd -v sqlvolume:/var/opt/mssql mssql-custom
```

This is some log which I think is related to the problem:

```
2024-03-12 03:23:51 Sqlcmd: 'SET NOCOUNT ON; Select SUM(state) from sys.databases': Unknown Option. Enter '-?' for help. 
2024-03-12 03:23:52 Sqlcmd: 'master': Unknown Option. Enter '-?' for help. 
2024-03-12 03:23:58 2024-03-11 20:23:58.55 Server Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf'. 
2024-03-11 20:23:58.60 Server Did not find an existing master data file /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf, copying the missing default master and other system database files. If you have moved the database location, but not moved the database files, startup may fail. To repair: shutdown SQL Server, move the master database to configured location, and restart.
```

This is my modified `setup.sql` file

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[mt_read]') AND type IN ('U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[mt_read]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mt_read] 
(
    [id] int  NOT NULL,
    [mt_name] varchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [mt_value] tinyint  NULL,
    [mt_time] datetime  NULL,
    [mt_quality] tinyint  NULL
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mt_read] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
```

I also tried the original `setup.sql` file with volume mounted, but it doesn't seem to work. Every other shell script and Dockerfile are the same as the original doc.

Comment: The SQL Server service doesn't execute as `root` (uid 0), it executes using a lesser-privileged `mssql` user. When you created the Docker volume did you permission it such that the uid and gid of the `mssql` user have full control?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes I did set mssql as owner of the app directory in the provided Dockerfile with some additional line: 
`RUN chown mssql /usr/config
RUN chown mssql /var/opt/mssql
WORKDIR /usr/config`

Comment: That won't help, though. When you use a Docker mount you're replacing whatever file system hierarchy was previously at the mount point so none of the contents nor permissions you applied in the image are known or accessible to the running container. You need to apply the permissions in the volume's file system.